# (X-Post) Tried switching between python verions on Linux. Ended up messing the whole thing. How to fix it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, python

I actually have three questions:

1. So I was trying to switch between **python2.7** and **python3.4**. I
   added both the alternatives using `update-alternatives`, giving
   priorities 1 and 2, respectively. It was set to manual mode so I
   configured it and tried running `python`. I don't know what happened
   here but it didn't work. It was working fine before setting the
   alternatives. *But*, instead, when I entered `python2` it worked
   just fine and launched **python2.7**. Similarly, entering `python3`
   launched **python3.4**. And this got me confused a bit.

   Isn't `python` supposed to be a generic command to run either v2.7
   or v.3.4 based on the configuration?
2. Now, *very gallantly*, I tried fixing this on my own, without
   feeling the need to look up what the problem was (naive, I know). I
   played around with it a bit. Removed the alternatives one-by-one
   using `remove` ( should've used `remove-all` *sighs* ) but,
   suspiciously enough, when I ran `update-alternatives --list python`,
   it still was showing the alternatives. *Confusion++*.

   What's the reason behind this? Why were those still being shown?
3. Anyway, assuming they were removed, I added the alternatives again
   and, in the hope of having fixed the problem, tried running
   `python`. Alas, it didn't work... displaying the following line:

   `bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad
   interpreter: No such file or directory`

   Next, tried running `python2`. Bam! This time, this one didn't work
   either! Producing a similar output:

   `bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad
   interpreter: No such file or directory`

   Same for `python3`. Output:

   `bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad
   interpreter: No such file or directory`

   So, what am I missing here and where lies the problem? Please
   elaborate.

PS : 
Pardon my ignorance. The questions might be silly but It's only recently that I started learning all this. I am pretty much a noob.

PPS :
I am running Xubuntu 15.04.

TIA.

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Protip. Do not ever mess around with python. Your package manager and other things are dependent on it, and python 2 and 3 are *very* different snakes. "python" is always python 2. "python 3" is always python 3.  What's the output of `which` for the three commands?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Nothing. It shows nothing. The next prompt appears. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

`Isn't python supposed to be a generic command to run either v2.7 or v.3.4 based on the configuration?`

[image: No no no no noooooooooooooooooo]

Here's what's basically the case. Python 2 and 3 are *different* and very distinct runtimes and languages, and the system will always assume python is python2, and python3 is python3. This is since many system critical applications rely on python, and are old enough to call "python" over "python3".

When writing your own apps, *call* the appropriate interpreter, rather than assuming.

I'm not sure what you've broken but it feels a lot like python 2/3 are stored elsewhere, and your actions broke the symlink (which is what alternatives does).

We don't know what else is broken, so it may be an excellent idea to back up all that you hold dear, rebuilt the system and *not taunt the serpent* until you have a better idea of what you're doing. A developer, or even a sysadmin typically would not need to do what you tried.

If you need to use *other* versions of python, consider [virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)